# I want to sort words(a-z) inside an input file and write that code into another file. But I am stuck with the sorting part as it shows some errors

Tags: c, visual-studio

> Learning c Programming by myself, 
>   Write a C program that makes a sorted list of all words found in a text file. Write the sorted list to an output file, along with the number of times each word appeared in the input file.
>
> ONLY C programming, do not use C++

This is the question guys..

I've tried my best, I am stuck with the sorting part because Im not sure if I can use an array to sort the words inside a file. Can someone help me with my attempt.

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp; // this is a file pointer
    char c[100]; // character to be written to the file

    fp = fopen("D:\\abc.txt", "w");

    while ((c[100] = getchar()) != EOF)
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            putc(c[i], fp);

    for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            if (strcmp(c[i], c[j]) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, c[i]);
                strcpy(c[i], c[j]);
                strcpy(c[j], temp); //char temp[1000]
            }
        }

    printf("Order of Sorted Strings:");
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        puts(c[i]);

    // close the opened file
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to help you with your homework assignments. If you have questions for homework assignments, address these to your teacher or the person who created the assignments.

Comment: I am trying to learn c programming on my own :(

Comment: `while ((c[100] = getchar()) != EOF)` is very odd. It stores a character one past the allowed range for that array. Perhaps you just want a single character or some sort of loop that increments the index, starting at 0. It seems from your description that you want an array of words, not characters.

Comment: How can I use an array of words?

Comment: @Hardworker99 Sorry about my down-vote then. Maybe edit your question telling you practice some exercises on your own and are not asking for help on a homework assignment. Give reference of these if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, hope you could help

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; should be `int main()`

Comment: It doesnt make a difference